# Why is torch.cuda.OutOfMemoryError not a valid error class?

Tags: exception, pytorch, pylance

I have the following code:

```py
        try:
            # faster, but requires more memory
            G = self.sparse.to_dense().t() @ self.sparse.to_dense()
        except torch.cuda.OutOfMemoryError:
            # slower, but requires less memory
            G = torch.sparse.mm(self.sparse.t(), self.sparse)
```

My pylance seems to think that `torch.cuda.OutOfMemoryError` is not a valid error class. (See image.)

[image: "OutOfMemoryError" is not a valid exception class]

However, when I run the code, the `torch.sparse.mm` runs, showing that the exception was detected.

Why does pylance think that it's invalid when it clearly works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this issue is that `torch.cuda.OutOfMemoryError` does not extend Python's `Exception` class. This issue has been fixed by PyTorch now. [109961](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/109961)